# Android logcat not shown exception full data?

Tags: android, logcat

recently in my android logcat i'm getting exception like this

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int ir.nililand.messenger.d.i.a()' on a null object reference
        at ir.nililand.messenger.pages.y.a(:267)
        at ir.nililand.messenger.pages.u.a(lambda)
        at ir.nililand.messenger.c.b.b(:86)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$g.a(:7065)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$g.a(:7107)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$v.a(:6012)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$v.a(:6279)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$v.b(:6118)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$v.d(:6114)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$c.a(:2303)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.a(:1627)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.a(:1587)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.e(:665)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(:4134)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(:3851)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.consumePendingUpdateOperations(:1897)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$a.run(:414)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:884)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:696)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:628)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:870)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:743)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
```

`ir.nililand.messenger.d.i.a()`  is my problem 
what i should to do for getting info like this ->

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.Serializable android.os.Bundle.getSerializable(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

i have this dependencies

```
dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'

....
}
```

i tryed `android:debuggable="true"`  in `AndroidManifest` but not solve the problem

how i can get full info from error ?

Comment: Is the package `ir.nililand.messenger.*` one of your packages or is it from a library? If it is from a library then the library itself is obfuscated the you won't be able to get the original class name as you don't have it. If it is from your app make sure to disable obfuscation for debug builds or use the mapping files that is generated when applying the obfuscation to translate the obfuscated package, class and method names back to their original name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `build.gradle (:app)` file, make sure `minifyEnabled` is `false`.

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

(Set it `true` when you release it into public (ex. Google Play Store) for obfuscation.)